# Division of two values

Tags: visualforce

I tried to divide **two values** in my class, but I get errors.
I tried with different ways, but is doesn't work.

```
public Integer TNQuote {get; set;}
public Integer AuBGruppen_B13 {get; set;}

1. TNQuote = AuBGruppen_B13 / Account.NumberOfEmployees);

2. TNQuote = (Integer.Valueof(AuBGruppen_B13) / Integer.Valueof(Account.NumberOfEmployees));

3. TNQuote = (Double.Valueof(AuBGruppen_B13) / Double.Valueof(Account.NumberOfEmployees));

4. TNQuote = (Integer.Valueof(AuBGruppen_B13) / Account.NumberOfEmployees);
```

Error 1: can't save the class, I get -> **Compile Error: Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments**

Error 2: possible to save the class, but if I open the visual force page I get -> **Invalid integer: common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexFieldToken@3950c48**

Error 3: possible to save the class, but if I open the visual force page I get -> **Invalid double: common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexFieldToken@cf690c1**

Error 4: can't save the class, I get -> **Compile Error: Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments**

Any ideas what I can change in my code?

Thanks a lot,
peX

Comment: You have a stray closing paren in #1.

Comment: Ok, but the error still popup.